# Select a column from two tables and put them into one

Tags: sql, ms-access

I don't just mean put them together as in I have one row in table 1 that says "Stuff" and another row in table 2 that says "Things" and that puts them together into a single cell that says "StuffThings", I just mean to simply have all the data in table 1 and table 2 combined into one column. For example....

```
Table 1:
Item 1
Item 2
Item 3

Table 2: 
Item 4
Item 5
Item 6

New Table:
Item 1
Item 2
Item 3
Item 4
Item 5
Item 6
```

All my attempts to do this have been something like

```
Select (Table1.Row + Table2.Row) AS JobNumber
FROM Table1, Table2;
```

It just does something like

```
Item 1Item 2
Item 1Item 3
  .....

etc.
```

Comment: what's the problem with your result?

Comment: Show your table definition. You probably just need a join. How do you decide what row in table1 goes with what row in table2?

Comment: My result is just a concatenation of the strings I'm querying into just one long string, that isn't something I want at all.

Comment: i think what you need is `UNION`

Comment: what is your desired output then? the `New Table`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think you want a UNION query:

```
SELECT Table1.Row AS JobNumber
FROM Table1
UNION
SELECT Table2.Row AS JobNumber
FROM Table2
```

Or UNION ALL, if you want duplicates.